# Guidelines for migration from Science Fiction & Fantasy

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm putting together [an effort on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13116/58193) to give users guidance for when they should migrate<sup>1</sup> a question from SFF to a different site on the network.

Movies & TV generally has a lot of overlap with SFF which means there is potential for a lot of migration of off topic content on SFF to M&TV.

It would be helpful if the M&TV community could put together some guidance on when they would like content from SFF migrating over here. Things to think about:

- Do you ever want it suggesting?
- What sorts of questions do you want migration suggesting for?
- Are there any topics to avoid?

Once the M&TV community has an idea of what guidelines they have for migration, could you post an answer to the linked post with them? If not let me know in the comments when it is ready and I can post it there.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Here migration means anything from formal migration to suggesting in a comment when to migrate content to a different site.</sub>

Comment: I'd have think some more but i can't envision pretty much anything on SF&F that would need to be migrated here. Granted some esoteric issue on show production might fit M&TV *better* but that would not necessarily invalidate it's topicness on SF&F.

Comment: @Paulie_D Other than any and all questions about films that are neither science-fiction nor fantasy?

Comment: @Paulie_D We do get questions on films/shows that aren't SFF-nal in anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well obviously but I don't see that happening. Certainly they get questions that aren't SF&F but those rarely involve M&TV issues *at least in my experience*.

Comment: @Paulie_D Don't worry about on-topicness on SFF; anyway we wouldn't migrate anything that's already on-topic where it is. This post seems more about M&TV's scope: which types of questions about non-scifi/fantasy films or TV series would you *want* or not want here? Regardless of how likely you think it is that such questions would be posted on SFF.